Problema al crear funcion propia con VBA en Excel
Estoy teniendo un problema que parece muy tonto a simple vista pero que no consigo arreglar al programar una funcion en un modulo con VBA en Excel.
Os pondria el codigo entero pero es que realmente el error principal debe estar en la primera línea de codigo:
Function CrearLote(fecha As Date, producto As String) As String

El problema esta que al intentar llamar la funcion en una casilla de excel, me deja introducir el primer parámetro pero no el segundo. Ni linkeado a una casilla ni introduciendo una cadena de texto manualmente.
He probado a cambiar por:
Function CrearLote(fecha As Date, fechaDos As Date) As String

y tampoco funciona.
No se donde puede estar el error ya que yo no conozco VBA, he programado el codigo en C++ y le he pedido a Edge que me lo pase a VBA

Voy a responder a mi propia pregunta para demostrar como a veces nos ofuscamos y no vemos lo que tenemos delante de nuestras narices.
El unico problema que había es que al llamar a la funcion lo estaba haciendo como
=CrearLote(A2, B2)

Cuando deberia ser
=CrearLote(A2;B2)1

Un saludo y buen dia a todos
